# How do I strike out line inside an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm2e, strikeout

Package I am using: `\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}`

My latex code:

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\label{alg:my-alg}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\caption{My algorithm}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\Input{$a,b,...$}
\Output{$R$}
statment1\; 
statment2\;
statment3\;
\lIf{$a>b$}{\KwRet{$a$}}
\KwRet{$b$}\;
\end{algorithm}
```

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using the `tikzmark` library:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}


\begin{document}



\begin{algorithm}[H]
\label{alg:my-alg}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\caption{My algorithm}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\Input{$a,b,...$}
\Output{$R$}
statment1\; 
statment2\;
statment3\;
\tikzmark{start}\lIf{$a>b$}{\KwRet{$a$\tikzmark{stop}}}
\KwRet{$b$}\;
\end{algorithm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[red,thick] ([yshift=0.5ex]pic cs:start) -- ([yshift=0.5ex]pic cs:stop);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I needed. I added opacity=0.6 (\draw{red,thick,opacity=0.6}) since I have a minus symbol that needs to be slightly visible.