# TikZ in floating algorithm2e

Tags: tikz-pgf, algorithm2e, tikzmark

I had a [question to strikeout a line in algorithm2e](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491374/how-do-i-strike-out-line-inside-an-algorithm). I got an answer that uses tikz to strikeout the line. This works great. However, if I use a floating algorithm2e (i.e. removing the `[H]` in `\begin{algorithm}`), then the strikeout would be in an incorrect position.

The issue can be solved by moving the tikz code inside the algorithm block but this introduces an extra line. How do I hide this extra line? Below is the code and a picture of what I need.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\label{alg:my-alg}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\caption{My algorithm}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\Input{$a,b,...$}
\Output{$R$}
statment1\; 
statment2\;
statment3\;
\tikzmark{start}\lIf{$a>b$}{\KwRet{$a$\tikzmark{stop}}}
\KwRet{$b$}\;

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[red,thick] ([yshift=0.5ex]pic cs:start) -- ([yshift=0.5ex]pic cs:stop);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the `overlay` picture up. Since it is overlay, it does not matter where you issue it as long as it is no the same page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\label{alg:my-alg}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\caption{My algorithm}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\Input{$a,b,...$}
\Output{$R$}
statment1\; 
statment2\;
statment3\;
\tikzmark{start}\lIf{$a>b$}{\KwRet{$a$\tikzmark{stop}}}\;
\KwRet{$b$}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[red,thick] ([yshift=0.5ex]pic cs:start) -- ([yshift=0.5ex]pic cs:stop);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I deleted my last comment by accident. Moving the tikz code outside the floating algorithm does indeed not work when you fill the document. I can see it in my document (can't share). I believe it only works when the floating algorithm and non-floating algorithm coincide which is the case here.

Anyway your solution works (kinda hackish), I don't why I never thought of taking out one of the semicolons.

Comment: @Topa AFAIK `tikzmark` sets coordinates at absolute page coordinates and with `remember picture,overlay` you can access them. There are exceptions when you put stuff in a savebox, adjustbox or whatever box and add transformations that Ti*k*Z does not know about. However, the above does have the `tikzpicture` inside the algorithm, so you do not have to worry about this.